# AngularJS Radio Buttons Do not handle events

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am having difficulty understanding why these radio buttons do not respond.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codezoo/wgas2783/)

I find that is I remove the "btn" class, I have better results, though I am unable to reproduce this with the JSFiddle. Thanks.

```
<div ng-app>
<div id="container-fluid" class="app-bg" ng-controller="ProfileSetupAgeCtrl">
    <div class="row profile-setup">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="btn btn-group btn-checkbox" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn btn-check active">
                    <input type="radio" checked ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="LT18">
                    < 18 </label>
                        <label class="btn btn-check">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="1824">18-24</label>
                        <label class="btn btn-check">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="2536">25-36</label>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <label class="btn btn-check">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="3745">37-45</label>
                        <label class="btn btn-check">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="4660">46-60</label>
                        <label class="btn btn-check">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.inputAgeGroup" value="GT60">> 60</label>
                        <br/> <span style="color: white">AgeGroup selected = {{inputAgeGroup}}</span>
                        <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I've modified your **jsfiddle** codes and I think this is what you are trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/wgas2783/7/. Just let me know if I am correct so I can post this as my answer and have some explaination.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks! What changes were made?

Comment: The JSFiddle as I built it was broken. I've rebuilt it and the problem is not reproduced, in other words, the radio buttons do not change the value of the model. I am reviewing to find what differences there are between the fiddle and my code files.

Comment: Latest JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codezoo/wgas2783/15/

Comment: Your latest **jsfiddle** demo seems working as expected. Did you the problem already solved?

Comment: No, the fiddle was wrong when I created it. The fiddle works but my code does not outside of the fiddle. I am stuck as to why.

Comment: Try to update the sample codes above with your current codes so I can help to investigate. By the way, is there any error in the browser console?